# Chart.js: Set different options to datasets

Tags: javascript, charts, lines, chart.js

BACKGROUND

I would like to achieve as shown in the image below using Chartjs Lines chart. Two lines, one with dots and one without dots.
I think a solution to this would be to set different options properties to the two datasets (lines).

PROBLEM

Chart datasets options is set globally for the whole chart. I don´t manage to set different options for the two datasets.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this could be achieved by setting the opacity of the dots to 0 so they do not display.

```js
var data = {
  labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
  datasets: [{
    label: "My First dataset",
    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
    data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
  }, {
    label: "My Second dataset",
    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0.2)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
    pointStrokeColor: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
    pointHighlightFill: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(0,0,0,0)",
    data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90]
  }]
};



var chart_canvas = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
var line_chart = new Chart(chart_canvas).Line(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.1/Chart.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" height="450" width="600"></canvas>
```